# PostgreSQL using COALESCE or other Conditional Expressions to SET field

Tags: postgresql

I have a PostgreSQL v10 DB with the following values:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  id INT,
  custom_fields jsonb not null default '{}'::jsonb,
  guest_profile_id character varying(100)
 );
INSERT INTO test (id, custom_fields) VALUES (1, '[{"protelSurname": "Smith", "servicio_tags": ["protel-info"], "protelUniqueID": "[{\"ID\":\"Test1-ID\",\"Type\":\"21\",\"ID_Context\":\"GHA\"}{\"ID\":\"4842148\",\"Type\":\"1\",\"ID_Context\":\"protelIO\"}]",    "protelGivenName": "Seth"}, {"value": "Test", "display_name": "Traces", "servicio_tags": ["trace"]}, {...}]');
INSERT INTO test (id, custom_fields) VALUES (2, '[{"protelSurname": "Smith", "servicio_tags": ["protel-info"], "protelUniqueID": "[{\"ID\":\"Test2-ID\",\"Type\":\"21\",\"ID_Context\":\"GHA\"},{\"ID\":\"4842148\",\"Type\":\"1\",\"ID_Context\":\"protelIO\"}]", "protelGivenName": "Seth"}, {"value": "Test2", "display_name": "Traces", "servicio_tags": ["trace"]}, {...}]');
INSERT INTO test (id, custom_fields) VALUES (3, '[{"value": "Test3-ID", "display_name": "Test", "servicio_tags": ["profile-id"]}, {...}]');
INSERT INTO test (id, custom_fields) VALUES (4, '[{"value": "Test4-ID", "display_name": "Test", "servicio_tags": ["person-name"]}, {...}]');
```

I have a query, which works and saves values from the custom_field row to the guest_profile_id column in the same row:

```
UPDATE guest_group
SET guest_profile_id = (
SELECT x ->> 'ID'
FROM jsonb_array_elements(custom_fields) AS field,
     jsonb_array_elements((field ->> 'protelUniqueID') :: jsonb) AS dd(x)
WHERE value @> '{"servicio_tags": ["protel-info"]}'::jsonb
AND x->>'ID_Context' = 'protelIO' 
);
```

But this only works for the first two rows. Therefor I want to use the next query-snippets in order to copy Test3-ID in row 3 to the guest_profile_id column and Test4-ID in row 4 to the guest_profile_id column.

1.

```
SELECT field ->>'value'
cross join lateral jsonb_array_elements(custom_fields) AS field
WHERE value @> '{"servicio_tags": ["profile-id"]}'::jsonb
```

2.

```
SELECT field ->>'value'
cross join lateral jsonb_array_elements(custom_fields) AS field
WHERE value @> '{"servicio_tags": ["person-name"]}'::jsonb
```

My problem: I do not know how to use `COALESCE` or other Conditional Expressions in order to chain those small queries. Because this should be possible if the first query uses `NULL` to set the field, `COALESCE` should help me to ignore this value and jump to the next query-snippet.

Desires result: I want that all the TestX-ID values from the table above are copied to the `guest_profile_id` column into the same row.

My try:

```
 UPDATE test
 SET guest_profile_id = COALESCE((
     SELECT x ->> 'ID'
     FROM jsonb_array_elements(custom_fields) AS field,
          jsonb_array_elements((field ->> 'protelUniqueID') :: jsonb) AS dd(x)
     WHERE value @> '{"servicio_tags": ["protel-info"]}'::jsonb
     AND x->>'ID_Context' = 'protelIO'),(
     SELECT field ->>'value'
     cross join lateral jsonb_array_elements(custom_fields) AS field
     WHERE value @> '{"servicio_tags": ["profile-id"]}'::jsonb),(
     SELECT field ->>'value'
     cross join lateral jsonb_array_elements(custom_fields) AS field
     WHERE value @> '{"servicio_tags": ["person-name"]}'::jsonb));
```

Gives me:

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "cross"
>   LINE 9:      cross join lateral jsonb_array_elements(custom_fields) ...

Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: Yes, it the query doesn't find a row it will be treated as if it returned `NULL`. So it really is just `SET guest_profile_id = COALESCE(first_select_query, second_select_query, …)`.

Comment: @Bergi I edited the question. Your suggestion gives me an error. Seems like I am doing smt wrong there ...

Comment: You need parens `guest_profile_id = COALESCE((first_select_query),(second_select_query), …)` and perhaps type casts `::varchar(100)`

Comment: @clamp thanks for the help. This gives me the following error: `ERROR:  syntax error at or near "cross"
LINE 9:      cross join lateral jsonb_array_elements(custom_fields) ...`

Comment: @clamp - I finally managed to put together the query: [Here a link to the fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=6cc3c7d202fc55af45a615bfbd9432f2)

Answer (score 1):

Some more brackets did the job around the `select_queries`:

`guest_profile_id = COALESCE((first_select_query),((second_select_query)), ((…)))`

```
UPDATE test
SET guest_profile_id = COALESCE((
SELECT x ->> 'ID'
FROM jsonb_array_elements(custom_fields) AS field,
     jsonb_array_elements((field ->> 'protelUniqueID') :: jsonb) AS dd(x)
 WHERE value @> '{"servicio_tags": ["protel-info"]}'::jsonb
 AND x->>'ID_Context' = 'protelIO' LIMIT 1),((
 SELECT field ->>'value'
 FROM jsonb_array_elements(custom_fields) AS field
 WHERE value @> '{"servicio_tags": ["profile-id"]}'::jsonb LIMIT 1)), ((
 SELECT field ->>'value'
 FROM jsonb_array_elements(custom_fields) AS field
 WHERE value @> '{"servicio_tags": ["person-name"]}'::jsonb LIMIT 1
 )));
```

Here the link to a fiddle: [Query which works](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=6cc3c7d202fc55af45a615bfbd9432f2)